# Finding the index of the minimum value in a list of arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a list with multiple arrays:

```
L = [
  array([-10, -8, -3, 2, 1]),
  array([-9, -4, -1, 3, 5]),
  array([-11, -5, -4, 0, 10])
]
```

How can I find the index of the lowest value the most efficiently?

For my example, the minimum value is -11 and the index is (2, 0), so the output should be (0, 2).

Comment: I would sort the arrays and then compare array[0] elements, provided sorting is not prohibited in the assignment. Always show the code you're working on to get targeted answers from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following?

import numpy as np

```
L = [
  np.array([-10, -8, -3, 2, 1]),
  np.array([-9, -4, -1, 3, 5]),
  np.array([-11, -5, -4, 0, 10])
]

L_2d = np.array(L)

min_index = np.unravel_index(L_2d.argmin(), L_2d.shape)
(min_index[0], min_index[1])
```

Comment: gives me a value error ("Truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous").

Comment: Please, try my full code as now edited, @Steven01123581321 -- it works fine here. Your `L` object is ill-defined!

Comment: Any idea why my array converts to a one dimensional array instead of a 2d array ?

Comment: Oh, but my arrays are of different length, can that be an issue?

Comment: You mean the rows of `L`? Have they unequal lengths?

Comment: Yes, so the arrays in the list can be of different length.

Comment: I'll ask a new question as this was not stated correctly in my question, so for my specific question, this was indeed the solution.

Comment: I have already a solution for that: we need padding.